# How to `transpose-chars' backwards

Tags: key-bindings, commands

I'm trying to make a trivial function that simply transposes chars backwards.

This is what I got so far:

```
(defun jd:backward-transpose-chars ()
  (interactive)
  (transpose-chars -1))

(define-key global-map (kbd "<C-y>") '(transpose-chars))

(define-key global-map (kbd "<C-S-y>") '(jd:backward-transpose-chars))
```

But it gives me the error:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument commandp
>   (jd:backward-transpose-chars))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra parenthesis, the correct synatx is:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "<C-y>") #'transpose-chars)
(define-key global-map (kbd "<C-S-y>") #'jd:backward-transpose-chars)
```

By the way, I don't think I'd bother with keybindings:
`transpose-chars` is bound by default to `C-t`, and to transpose
backwards you can do `C-- C-t` (that's control minus, control t).